# Migrate users from AWS cognito to firebase?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, amazon-cognito

I'm in the process of migrating users from AWS to firebase. One major issue I've hit on is resolving the users ID to their database data.

When a user logs in I create a profile for them in DynamoDB indexed against their cognito identity ID.

Unfortunately (and perhaps with good reason) Amazon does not provide a clear path to find a users identity ID without them logging in. While this is good for their privacy the flipside is when it comes time to move them to firebase I don't know what data to grab for the user from dynamodb to move over to firebase.

The long and short of it is I have all the users data but no way to connect the data with the individual user unless they login and gain access to their identity id, but I need to be able to do this to migrate them over to firebase.

I'm currently flirting with the idea of having a migration process trigger when a user logs in to create a firebase account and move their data across but at the same time this could cause issues for individual users who might encounter problems that could be caught in a mass migration.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but I think you can use this API to lookup your AWS cognito users: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html
The `sub` field on the user should provide you with each user's `uid`.

You can then use Firebase CLI SDK to import the users to Firebase Auth DB: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authimport

Comment: This can be used to import users but it doesn't provide a way to connect a users uid to their identity id.

The issue is that I have data on users stored in dynamodb using their identity id (format: ap-south-east-2:xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxz) and separately have user  identifying information with the 'sub' as you mentioned but no way of connecting the two.

Comment: What method of sign in were you using to sign in users in the first place with AWS cognito?

Comment: I'm using the cognito angular library (AmazonCognitoIdentity, etc)

Comment: How are you authenticating your users? username/password, OAuth, SAML etc. Where is this identity id coming from?

Answer (score 1):

**Staying with UserPools**

First of all regarding the following part in your question,

> When a user logs in I create a profile for them in DynamoDB indexed
>   against their cognito identity ID.
>
> Unfortunately (and perhaps with good reason) Amazon does not provide a
>   clear path to find a users identity ID without them logging in. While
>   this is good for their privacy the flipside is when it comes time to
>   move them to firebase I don't know what data to grab for the user from
>   dynamodb to move over to firebase.

This you can achieve using the Username field which can be used as the ID for the User Identity. This way you can store the Username in DynamoDB referencing to the Cognito User in the UserPool.

**Migrating from UserPools and Querying Users data**

If you really plan to do the migration you can use the `list_users` method in [AWS Boto3 SDK](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.list_users) to list all the users in a UserPool.

```
response = client.list_users(
    UserPoolId='string',
    AttributesToGet=[
        'string',
    ],
    Limit=123,
    PaginationToken='string',
    Filter='string'
)
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, how can I use the Username field as the ID for the user identity? The user identities stored in the dynamodb are GUIDs not usernames, is there a way to check the guid against an actual username?

Comment: @tweetypi did you manage to successfully migrate users from cognito to firebase in the end?